# What event are the lyrics of "Wild Wild Western" by Okay referring to?

Tags: 19th-century

The (German) lyrics refer to a day 8th Sep 1878 and to Cheyennes. Unluckily full text is copyright-blocked. (Best I can offer is the [Youtube vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rk6uGgg_3DM)!) Googling around hints that it refers to [Northern Cheyenne Exodus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Cheyenne_Exodus), but Wikipedia doesn't mention this exact date. Anyone who can be more specific what the band alludes to?

Comment: I think this question would be improved by including the lyrics, perhaps with an English translation.

Comment: @User65535, I agree, but I've found it difficult to find [those lyrics](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/OKAY-2/The-Wild-Wild-Western)

Comment: @User65535: Video added (most lyrics is English)

Comment: I see a few references to the exodus having begun on the 9th: https://mynehistory.com/items/show/485?tour=4&index=21

Comment: Looking through the WP page, it looks like the leaders started telling everyone to start gathering what they need to leave on the 9th, so it seems a reasonable presumption that the 8th was the day those leaders got together and decided to leave.